# How to get ApplicationScoped producer in Java SE via weld?

Tags: java, scope, cdi, weld

I'm trying to implement dependency injection in my Java SE program using weld and I have problems using an application scoped producer. This is a PoC of my problem with minimal code. The `MyBean` class:

```
public class MyBean implements Serializable{
  private int value;

  public MyBean(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }

  public int getValue() {
    return value;
  }

  public void setValue(int value) {
    this.value = value;
  }
}
```

The injection point:

```
@Path("api")
public class MyResource implements Serializable {
  @Inject
  private MyBean bean;

  @GET
  @Path("bean")
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response getBean() {
    return Response.ok(bean).build();
  }
}
```

The producer that I want it's produced instance be `@ApplicationScoped` is:

```
public class BeanProducer {

  @Produces
  @ApplicationScoped
  public MyBean beanProducer(){
    System.out.println("producing");
    return new MyBean(42);
  }
}
```

And it all bound together in a main class:

```
public class Main {
  public void main(@Observes ContainerInitialized event) {
    try {
      URI baseUri = UriBuilder.fromUri("http://localhost").port(1234).build();
      ResourceConfig config = new ResourceConfig(MyResource.class)
          .register(JacksonFeature.class);
      SimpleServer server = SimpleContainerFactory.create(baseUri, config);
      System.in.read();
      server.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

When I try to run this, I get following exception:

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001410: The
>   injection point [BackedAnnotatedField] @Inject @ApplicationScoped
>   private MyResource.bean has non-proxyable dependencies    at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:392)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPoint(Validator.java:293)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateGeneralBean(Validator.java:134)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateRIBean(Validator.java:167)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateBean(Validator.java:530)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:68)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.ConcurrentValidator$1.doWork(ConcurrentValidator.java:66)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:60)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.executor.IterativeWorkerTaskFactory$1.call(IterativeWorkerTaskFactory.java:53)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) Caused by:
>   org.jboss.weld.exceptions.UnproxyableResolutionException: WELD-001435:
>   Normal scoped bean class MyBean is not proxyable because it has no
>   no-args constructor - Producer Method [MyBean] with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default] declared as [[BackedAnnotatedMethod] @Produces
>   @ApplicationScoped public BeanProducer.beanProducer()].   at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableClassException(Proxies.java:214)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.util.Proxies.getUnproxyableTypeException(Proxies.java:178)
>     at
>   org.jboss.weld.bootstrap.Validator.validateInjectionPointForDeploymentProblems(Validator.java:390)
>     ... 12 more

If I define a scope for producer, it won't work.
If I set the injection point scope as `@ApplicationScoped` and producer without any scope, it works as I want, means I will have a single instance of the bean in the entire lifecycle of my app.

But setting the scope of the injection point as `@ApplicationScoped` is the same as default scope, ie. a new instance for each request.

What is the reason behind all of this?

Answer (score 1):

This happens because `@ApplicationScoped` is a normal scope, it needs to be proxyable.  To be proxyable, you need a no-args constructor.

To clarify one of your points

```
it works as I want, means I will have a single instance of the bean in the entire lifecycle of my app.
```

This isn't accurate.  Injection points don't define scope, the producer does.  There's just no type-safe way to do this in Java, since you can have a producer field.

Comment: Adding a default constructor makes the dependencies ambiguous because weld would not know whether use the producer or directly inject the bean itself.